# Vim: Yank distant line without moving

Tags: vim

Suppose I have the following (* = cursor):

```
...
*
Kittens
Puppies
Humans
...
```

How do I yank the "Humans" (cursor relative 3rd line) while leaving the cursor in place?

Preferably in one motion or one (generic) command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
:+3y
```

It uses the range `+3` , that it is the point where it will begin to yank. and by default it does one line.

**UPDATE**: If you wanted to copy both the second and third line without moving cursor, you would use same command but with a range of two points, like:

```
:+2,+3y
```

It would copy both `Puppies` and `Humans`.

Answer (score 3):

Now, for those who are wondering, based on Birei's answer, you can also do `:ny`, where `n` is the line number you want to yank. This is actually what I was looking for when I came to this page, and is helpful if you've got `set number` on and don't want to count relative lines.

Now, I wonder, how to perform this yank to a particular register! :D

Answer (score 2):

My [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140) combines yanks and puts into various short mappings; e.g. with `3[f` you can fetch a line 3 lines below the current line and put it below the current line.